# fullPage.js - background videos in multiple slides

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, video, fullpage.js

I'm looking for a way to have full page video backgrounds in the same section using fullpage.js. Essentially what is achieved here, but with a full background video in each slide:

http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/videoBackground.html

The CSS used for the video is relatively straight forward:

```
#myVideo{
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        top:0;
        right:0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        background-color: black; /* in case the video doesn't fit the whole page*/
        background-image: /* our video */;
        background-position: center center;
        background-size: contain;
        object-fit: cover; /*cover video background */
        z-index:3;
    }
```

However this does not work with multiple slides due to the way sections span the length of all the slide divs. Is there an alternative solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a relative position for the slides.

```
.slide{
   position:relative;
}
```

And then place your absolute positioned videos inside.

Comment: Unfortunately this introduces an overlapping issue, where the second slide overlaps the first: https://i.snag.gy/j7M1Le.jpg


The only thing that appears to solve it is to define the width of the slide as 51%, however this breaks the slider.

Comment: I'm not going to lose more time on this answer. But your problem has nothing to do with my proposed answer, which is correct. It has to do with your CSS knowledge.

Comment: For anyone who needs the solution, overflow: hidden needs to be applied to the slides, as Alvaro points out in the CSS this is a Chrome (Mac) specific bug.